# Динамическое появление меню в ToolBar`e

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Добрый день. У меня есть 2 поля `EditText` пустые по умолчанию и пункт меню, который невидимый по умолчанию. Я пытаюсь сделать появление пункта меню, когда оба поля `EditText` не пустые. Но приложение крашится, когда оба поля не пустые, что я делаю не так?
Метод TextWatcher:

```
private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {       }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        checkFieldsForEmptyValues();
    }};
```

Сама проверка содержимого полей:

```
boolean checkFieldsForEmptyValues(){
        String s1 = log.getText().toString();
        String s2 = pass.getText().toString();

        if(!s1.equals("") && !s2.equals("") ){
            MenuItem nextItem = myMenu.findItem(R.id.loginim);
            View nextItemView = findViewById(nextItem.getItemId());
            nextItemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Ну и оставшийся код:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
        Toolbar mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);

         log = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_log);
         pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pass);

        log.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        pass.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

        checkFieldsForEmptyValues();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Где может быть ошибка?
**UPDATE** LogCat:

> 03-09 18:25:01.492 6276-6276/comtime88.vk.myappE/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   comtime88.vk.myapp.LoginActivity.checkFieldsForEmptyValues(LoginActivity.java:56)
>   at
>   comtime88.vk.myapp.LoginActivity$1.afterTextChanged(LoginActivity.java:37)
>   at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7247) at
>   android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:8891)
>   at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
>   at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
>   at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
>   at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
>   at
>   android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:222)
>   at
>   android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:136)
>   at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5385) at
>   android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5204) at
>   android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2609) at
>   android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7205) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1920)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1395)
>   at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2370) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3651)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Откуда у вас myMenu берется и какая ошибка в логах? может проще добавлять/убирать или enabl'ить/disabl'ить пункт меню при этих условиях - (`toolbar.getMenu().add(myItem)`)?

Comment: @AbrogPetrovich меню инициализировано в самом начале, я просто не указал его: Menu myMenu; . Логи сейчас выложу в вопросе, по поводу enable/disable, хотелось бы именно появление элемента меню..

Comment: м! он `nextItem.getItemId()` берет не Id из ресурсов, а Id меню. Сделайте сразу `nextItem.setVisibility(false/true)`, Вообще - странные манипуляции с поиском View :)

Comment: @AbrogPetrovich ДА, это заработало! Спасибо Вам большое!  Замена на `nextItem.setVisible(true);` помогла.

Comment: @DenisMolodec, было бы хорошо, если б вы своё решение в виде ответа опубликовали)

Comment: извиняюсь, было поздно и я забыл об этом.

Answer (score 1):

**Решение:**

```
MenuItem nextItem = myMenu.findItem(R.id.loginim);
        nextItem.setVisible(true);
```

вместо

```
MenuItem nextItem = myMenu.findItem(R.id.loginim);
            View nextItemView = findViewById(nextItem.getItemId());
            nextItemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Не совсем понял почему, но это работает :)